# FactoryGirl uninitialized constant InvalidVoice

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

Trying to learn RSpec and FactoryGirl when I came across this error.

```
Failure/Error: post :create, voice: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_voice)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant InvalidVoice
```

Below is a simple RSpec on the voice_controller

```
describe '#create' do

        context "with valid inputs" do
            it "creates and increase Voice count by 1" do
                expect{
                    post :create, voice: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:voice)
                }.to change(Voice, :count).by(1)
            end

            it "redirects to show page" do
                post :create, voice: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:voice)
                expect(response).to redirect_to Voice.last
            end
        end

        context "with invalid inputs" do
            it "does not increase Voice count" do
                expect{
                    post :create, voice: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_voice)
                }.not_to change(Voice, :count)
            end

            it 'renders #new again' do
                post :create, voice: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_voice)
                expect(response).to render_template :new
            end
        end
    end
```

Right now, all the **context "with valid inputs" do** will pass. In the **with invalid inputs** context however, it seems like FG is not registering :invalid_voice as a valid input.

Here is my FG

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :voice do
    title "MyString"
    opinion "MyText"
  end

  factory :invalid_voice do
    title ""
    opinion ""
  end

end
```

For this project, an invalid input simply means empty inputs. So if either title or opinion are empty, it is invalid and should return an error / redirect to the **new** method.

I tried setting "" to nil as well as removing one one of the attributes completely, but the error still persists.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

It appears that the following works. But can someone please tell me why?

```
factory :invalid_voice, parent: :voice do
    title nil
  end
```

Comment: I have explained the reason in my answer. Please take a look and let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factory :invalid_voice, parent: :voice do
    title nil
end
```

This works because, when you define `voice` as the parent of `invalid_voice`, this means `invalid_voice` is inherited from `voice` and is a kind of `voice`.

Without this, it was not working and getting this error:

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant InvalidVoice
```

Because, you don't have any class named `InvalidVoice` in your code. But, you only have `Voice` class.

You can create multiple factories for the same class using `Inheritence`. And, you are creating two factories `:voice` and `:invalid_voice` for one class `Voice`.

That's what you are doing this: `factory :invalid_voice, parent: :voice` to specify that `Voice` is the associated class for `invalid_voice` factory and that works as you already have a `Voice` class present in your code.

Comment: I see, so it seems that all factories must be related to the models. Thanks!!